# Bulk APIs delete, update, upsert request format

Tags: bulk-api

I have created an object for Contact in salesforce. I am trying to delete it using curl command. Please help me with the format of the request. I am using json format

```
[{"Id":"0032800000i6MyTAAU"},{"Id":"0032800000i6MyUAAU"}]
```

This returns Invalid Batch, Batch not completed. I also tried giving just the ids, id in csv format. What is the correct format for delete

Also need the request format for update

Comment: please include the full curl command

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer by a hit and trial : 
The delete operation requires the id in this format.

```
[{"id":"0032800000i6OllAAE"}]
```

Also the curl command would be

```
curl -X POST -H "X-SFDC-Session: sessionId" -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8"  -d '[{"id":"<id>"}]'"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/async/38.0/job/jobId/batch"
```